# How do I opt out my Node application from my split-tunneling VPN?

Tags: node.js, linux, vpn, tunnel

My ubuntu laptop is currently functioning as a web server. I have ports forwarded to its internal IP, and my network’s public IP is referenced in a DNS record for a domain of mine. The server app is being deployed using Node. If it makes any difference, I launch using sudo and use pm2 in the launch command to create a persistent instance, and then internally the app is using express, http, and https modules.

For privacy reasons, I want to use a VPN for all traffic besides inbound/outbound traffic to that web server. I’m using PIA VPN, which supports split tunneling. Meaning I can enable/disable VPN tunneling on a per-app basis either in an opt-in or opt-out fashion. Ideally I want to have node opted out and everything else defaults to using the VPN.

(probably irrelevant) but IAP VPN split tunneling also also has a rule I can set for ‘Routed Packets - includes most containers and virtual machines’, as well as a rule for ‘Name Servers’.

So I tried adding app rules for usr/bin/node, usr/bin/pm2, usr/bin/npm all set to ‘Bypass VPN’. ‘Everything Else’ is then set to ‘Use VPN’. With this setup, the app is failing all of its outbound requests. for example,
http.get(‘host’: ‘api.ipofy.org’, ‘port’: ‘80’, ‘path’: ‘/‘), which is supposed to return my public IP, instead errors with this

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:80
```

If instead, I set everything to bypass the VPN by default and only enable it for certain apps that I especially want protection for (web browsers for instance) then the node app functions fine. But I’d rather have the default be for all apps use the VPN, and only Node is opted out.

I’m wondering if there are any other binaries I need create a ‘Bypass VPN’ rule for so my app will function correctly under my preferred approach. Or just any solution in general that will get my app working in a VPN opt-out scenario.

Thanks in advance!